# What is the story of sage AshvalAyana?

Tags: rishi, life

Ashvalayana (ITRANS : AshvalAyaNa) is a famous rishi associated with a shAkha of Vedas and vedanga sutras.

What is his life story ?

What are some important texts written by him ?

Answer (score 2):

Rishi  Asvalayana is associated with  Asvalayana Shaka of the Rig Veda. which is said to be lost in current time. Asvalayana was  said to be disciple of Rishi Shaunaka. He followed two branches of Rig-Veda i.e. Bashkal & Shakal.

We find some brief information about Rishi  Asvalayana in this  introduction of  [**Kaivalyopanishad**](https://www.esamskriti.com/e/Spirituality/Upanishads-Commentary/Kaivalyopanishad-1.aspx) .

> In the Vedantic literature, Asvalayana is  well-known as a great
> teacher of Rig Veda. Even today, many who belong to the  tradition of
> Rig Veda follow the Vedic rituals formulated by Rishi Asvalayana. 
> Before he became a great teacher, **Asvalayana is said to have
> received his  education in Brahma Vidya from Lord Brahma, The Creator,
> who is referred to as Lord  Parameshti.,** The Great Teacher.

---

The **Asvalayana Grhyasutra and  Asvalayana Srautasutra** are attributed to the sage Asvalayana and are  [**associated**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitareya_Brahmana%23Identification_with_Asvalayana_Brahmana&ved=0ahUKEwjX3aPQksHYAhVKsY8KHU0iD5YQpYkCCDAoATAB&usg=AOvVaw0PIBySkAtzvjP4uWjh5V3w)  with the Aitareya Brahmana.

Asvalayana Srautasutra consisting of 12 chapters.  [**Asvalyana Grihasutra**](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/grihya/asva.asp#3.6)  consists of four chapters and is further divided into 48 kandikas or subsections. It discusses the 16 Samskaras and rules for recitation of the Vedas.

---

We find mentioning of one rishi Asvalayana in [**Prashna Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145276.html)  also.

> कौसल्यश्चाश्वलायनो 1.1
>
> kausalyaścāśvalāyano
>
> Kausalya by name. Âsvalâyana, the son of Asvala.

---

**Note** -<sup>Very Less information is known and available online  about sage Asvalayana. And this compilation is an attempt to gather it here. If anyone is having  some more information regarding this topic Pls. feel free to add it in answer.</sup>